# Can interacting Hamiltonians always be written in second quantized form?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, many-body

Is it always possible to write interacting Hamiltonian in a second quantized matrix form like we do it for non-interacting form

$$H=\sum _{\alpha\beta}C_\alpha^\dagger h_{\alpha\beta} C_\beta$$

where $H$ is many body hamiltonian, $C_\alpha$ are second quantized operators, and $h_{\alpha\beta}$ is an $N\times N$ matrix?

Comment: I'm supposing Einstein summation is being assumed, in which case, shouldn't it be $h^{\alpha\beta}$?

Comment: yes Einstein summation was assumed now I have edited the equation for clearity

Comment: If higher order interaction(larger than 2) is considered, I think turning the interacting Hamiltonian into a quadratic form is always impossible. In a terms of path integral, only the Gaussian type is analytically solvable. A general kinds of Hamiltonian(or Lagrangian) with interaction can't be switched into Gaussian type.

Comment: Could you explain your definition of "interacting Hamiltonian"?  I would say those are exactly the Hamiltonians which cannot be written as a quadratic form in creation/annihilation operators, but you seem to have a different definition in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Given any Hamiltonian $H'$, let $C_1=1$ be the identity operator and $h_{11}:=H'$ be a $1\times 1$-matrix.

(If you want to have $h$ take values in a field, the fact that you propose a discrete sum over states will be insufficient if the Hamiltonian involves operators with a continuous spectrum like the standard momentum operator. I see you also leave no space for vacuum energy. Also, you'd have to do a lot of tricks to implement "double sum over nearest neighbors" like the [t-J model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-J_model) Hamiltonian which involves a term $\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}(\dots+a^+_ia_i\,a^+_ja_j)$.)

Comment: Why the downvote? Is my solution just too much outside the box or is it wrong? Going passed that, does the discrete sum remark not give a negative answer to the question?